# Matlab: Cumulative Frequency of Occurence

Tags: matlab

I am looking at computing the cumulative frequency of occurrence of a matrix A.

Considering we have a matrix with the following values

```
A = [...
    -76     23    -0.23; ...
    -0.23   23    -0.23; ...
    -76     23    -0.23; ...
    -0.23   21     0.23; ...
    -76     23    -0.23  ];
```

*Note that row 1, 2 and 4 are the same.

How would one undertake a CFO (Cumulative Frequency of Occurrence) of A(3,:) occurring the matrix?

Comment: I don't understand. What's the CFO of A(3,:)? Can you give your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I don't think that there is a super clean way to do this. But it may look something like this:

```
modelRow = A(3,:);
rowMatches = A(:,1)==modelRow(1)  &  A(:,2)==modelRow(2)  &  A(:,3)==modelRow(3);
cumulativeOccurance = cumsum(rowMatches);
```

Which results in:

```
cumulativeOccurance =
     1
     1
     2
     2
     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if @Pursuit answer should work, I'd like to propose mine

```
pattern = -0.23   21   0.23;

CFO = sum(ismember(A, pattern, 'rows')) / size(A,1);
```

If you don't want A(3,:) to be included in your CFO, just do

```
CFO = (sum(ismember(A, pattern, 'rows')) - 1) / size(A,1);
```